# select grand children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling to select my img Element in a list so i can switch its class on and off.
I've tried different way to select it but its the first picture of my list that lights up, even when mouseover on the second/third/... div of the list.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="container" onmouseover="toggleImgColor()" onmouseout="toggleImgColor()">
      <div class="container-title">
        <h3 class="title />
        <img id="pic" class="greyImg" />
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
function toggleImgColor() {
  $(this).find("img").toggleClass("greyImg");
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: All images in your list have the same id: 'pic' ? If they do jQuery will always select the first one

Comment: @dimlucas Only if he uses the ID as a selector though. But I hear you. ALL ID's should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".container").hover(function() {
      $("#pic").toggleClass("greyImg");
   });
});
```

Comment: Oeh careful. Your last character is a colon instead of a semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, You also can edit the answer by edit option. Again Thank you for correcting it. Doing great. Cheers !!

Comment: I thought that was exclusively for moderators and such so just stayed away :). Thank you. I will do so in future.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `this` inside the `toggleImgColor()` in html like `toggleImgColor(this)`, and catch that as parameter in javascript function. This will pass current hovered DOM object to `toggleImgColor` function and you can then use that to show that specific div.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="container" onmouseover="toggleImgColor(this)" onmouseout="toggleImgColor(this)">
      <div class="container-title">
        <h3 class="title />
        <img class="greyImg" />
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleImgColor(item) {
  $(item).find("img").toggleClass("greyImg");
}
```

Comment: thx too, works aswell with: onmouseover="toggleImgColor.call(this)"